# How can I use --incremental from TypeScript compiler API?

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

TypeScript recently added the "--incremental" compiler option.

How can I use it with the TS compiler API?

This program does not generate a .tsbuildinfo file, and does not run faster the second time:

```js
import * as ts from "typescript";

const program = ts.createProgram(["./src/foo.ts"], {
    incremental: true,
    tsBuildInfoFile: "./tsbuildinfo"
});
const emit = program.emit();
console.log('emitted', JSON.stringify(emit)); // { emitSkipped: false, diagnostics: []}
```

I don't think TS is actually paying attention to the path to the tsBuildInfo file, since it makes no difference if I set the `tsBuildInfoFile` option to nonsense like "@@@@@@".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `tsBuildInfoFile` will be ignored when using a regular program. You will need to create a program using the [`ts.createIncrementalProgram`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/b57b5fe5ee31a334a1e2b63eced4ba5a046bff61/lib/typescript.d.ts#L4475) function.

For example:

```
import * as ts from "typescript";

const program = ts.createIncrementalProgram({
    rootNames: ["./src/foo.ts"],
    options: {
        incremental: true,
        tsBuildInfoFile: "./tsbuildinfo"
    }
});
const emit = program.emit();
console.log('emitted', JSON.stringify(emit));
```

Also, if you are creating a host it seems you might need to use the [`ts.createIncrementalCompilerHost`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/b57b5fe5ee31a334a1e2b63eced4ba5a046bff61/lib/typescript.d.ts#L4466) function to create it.

Comment: Thanks! How did you find this out? Also, is this a bug? I'd expect createProgram(['./foo.ts'], { incremental: true, tsBuildInfoFile: '.tsb'}) to not type-check and to throw a runtime error rather than silently do the wrong thing.

Comment: I'm not seeing `ts.createIncrementalProgram` on typescript@latest (version 3.5.3)

Comment: @MaxHeiber it's only available in 3.6 RC. I found out from the 3.6 RC [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-6-rc/) and looking at the source of [tsc.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/tsc/tsc.ts).

Comment: @MaxHeiber I don't think it's a bug. It seems the decision on which program to use is made at a high level based on the compiler options. Sometimes people may be creating a program from compiler options without wanting to use the build info file, so it would be inconvenient if they had to strip out those compiler options before using it.

Comment: @MaxHeiber hey Max!  In case it helps it might be worth looking at this PR by Sheetal of TypeScript team: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/pull/1017

You can see the APIs that Sheetal makes use of there.

Comment: how does this relate to [Using-the-Compiler-API/writing-an-incremental-program-watcher](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API#writing-an-incremental-program-watcher)

Comment: @CraigHicks that's how the compiler implements the `--watch` functionality. This is more related to the [incremental compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#incremental).

Comment: I had trouble getting that API example to work - perhaps it is out of date.  Looking inside `lib/tsc.js` it seems to use `ts.createSolutionBuilderWithWatchHost` and `ts.createSolutionBuilderWithWatch`, and it will use incremental (at least when the tsconfit is set so.)